# How can I randomize a single value in JavaScript object using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I randomize the values of these objects?
And can you assign it randomly every 10-20 minutes?

```
const fs = require('fs');

var winrate = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);

// create a JSON object
const gamesg = [{
    "ID": 1,
    "GAME_CAMPS": "SG",
    "GAMENAME": "FISHING GOD",
    "IMG_PATH": "./SG/1 FISHING GOD.png",
    "GAME_IMG": "1 FISHING GOD.png",
    "WINRATE": winrate
},......................................{
    "ID": 55,
    "GAME_CAMPS": "SG",
    "GAMENAME": "HONEY HUNTER",
    "IMG_PATH": "./SG/55 HONEY HUNTER.png",
    "GAME_IMG": "55 HONEY HUNTER.png",
    "WINRATE": winrate
}
```

];

Comment: What random values? It appears the keys are not random. Are the entire records to be random or just the order random? Apparently the folder names for the images is not random - so that part of `IMG_PATH` value is not random yet the other parts are? There is so much detail left out of the question. Please provide the relevant details.

Comment: "WINRATE": winrate

Comment: change winrate to a function like so `var winrate = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);` then use it as a function `..., "WINRATE": winrate(), ...` you get random value everytime.

Comment: [What is JSON anyway](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for creating a random value and to place that value into a JavaScript object:

```js
const gamesg = [{
  "WINRATE": 0
}, {
  "ID": 1,
  "WINRATE": 0
}, {
  "ID": 2,
  "WINRATE": 0

}, {
  "ID": 3,
  "WINRATE": 0

}, {
  "ID": 4,
  "WINRATE": 0
}];

let output = gamesg
  .map(g => { g.WINRATE = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101); return g});
console.log(output);
```